# Obtain currently selected datein CalendarView [UWP] [C#]

Tags: c#, uwp, textblock, calendarview

In my UWP C# app I want to display the currently selected date of a CalendarView in a TextBlock, I know I should use the SelectedDatesChanged event to update the TextBlock but I cannot find any code to obtain and parse the date.

Comment: What stops you from using the `SelectedDatesChanged` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `args.AddedDates` to get Date from `SelectedDatesChanged` event

```
private void CalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var myDate = args.AddedDates.First();  //Since args.AddedDates returns collection we should use First to get the first item
    MyTextBlock.Text = myDate.ToString();  //You can convert DateTime into different format using myDate.ToString(format);
}
```

To learn more about [Use patterns to format dates and times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/use-patterns-to-format-dates-and-times), [DateTimeOffset.ToString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351892(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How can this be done by Binding in XAML, i.e. binding the textbox's TEXT property to the selected date?